# One scource code multiple web applications

Tags: php

i have a project to work on , has one source code and they need multiple versions

i.e : different domains to work under the same code...

let me know what technology behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the domains to all point to the same codebase, simply set your server to point all the domains to the same directory. Without more information on your hosting setup, we can only give you generalities.

If you're using some sort of shared hosting with a control panel, you likely have "Parked Domains" functionality available. If you control your own environment, each domain probably has its own folder in `/var/www/`; simply remove the extra folders and symlink their names to a canonical copy of your codebase.

Comment: you'r correct.But here i have present contents dynamically relevent to the domain the request comes. what is the best method to do this.I do not use framework on this CMS so would i have to use n different site folders for n domains or would it better to keep them all dynamically to load.

Comment: Check out `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in PHP. It will contain the domain name the user used to access the site. You can then handle the user differently depending on which domain name they came in on.